# How to add disabled properties for textboxes on a css file?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, background-color

I'm not an expert on CSS, so please excuse the possible incorrect words I might use.

I have the following css file that I usually use in my webforms on .NET
styles.css

then, one of the methods inside is:

```
.tbox
{
    border-right: #728d8d 1px solid;
    border-top: #728d8d 1px solid;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-left: #728d8d 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #728d8d 1px solid;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: url(images/boxBorders/formshdw.gif) no-repeat -4px -4px #fff;
}
```

which I usually use for textboxes. Now, the problem here is that whenever I disable a textbox, it keeps the same properties (doesn't turn gray to let the user know form the looks of it that the textbox is disables). I started looking for a solution, and the only thing I came up with was:

```
input[disabled='disabled'] 
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}

input[readonly]
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}
```

However, I believe those are added to each form that I would use. Is there a way that .tbox can inherit those properties? It doesn't matter if only one of the two works, as long as I can prevent an user from typing and switching the textbox color, I'm good to go.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply those styles to just elements with the .tbox class, just do:

```
.tbox input[disabled='disabled'] 
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}

.tbox input[readonly]
{
  /* Your CSS Styles */
  background-color:#F0F0F0 !important; 
  color:#303030 !important;
}
```

That's the cascading part of CSS :)

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion. It didn't work out. An Example:

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxInvoiceExtNumber" runat="server" CssClass="tbox" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>

When server side I run:
tbxInvoiceExtNumber.Enabled = false;

It doesn't happen anything to it other that disabling it.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the asp syntax - so hopefully someone else can chime in

Comment: "It doesn't happen anything to it other that disabling it." .... isent that what you want?????

Comment: Well, I Want it to be disabled, and at the same time change the background color to make it look that it's disabled.

Comment: Does setting enabled to false does that translate to a readonly attribute or a disable='disable' attribute?

Comment: Thats true, for some reason the CSS style is not applied. Please check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should create separte classes for each behaviour:

```
.tbox-disabled 
{
  background-color:black !important; 
  color:white !important;
}

.tbox-readonly
{
  background-color:black !important; 
  color:yellow !important;
}
```

Then in your object you must set the appropriate CSS class-name and behavior:

**Read-Only:** *CssClass="tbox-readonly"* AND *ReadOnly="true"*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxInvoiceExtNumber" 
             runat="server" 
             CssClass="tbox-readonly" 
             Width="50px" 
             ReadOnly="true">
</asp:TextBox>
```

**Disabled:** *CssClass="tbox-disabled"* AND *Enabled="false"*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxInvoiceExtNumber" 
             runat="server" 
             CssClass="tbox-disabled" 
             Width="50px" 
             Enabled="false">
</asp:TextBox>
```

You can also apply CSS and behavior programmatically like so:

```
tbxInvoiceExtNumber.CssClass="tbox-disabled";
tbxInvoiceExtNumber.Enabled="false";
```